# Ligatures missing

Tags: fonts, ligatures

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avant}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}                                                                                                
\begin{document}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

fi ff
\end{document}
```

I was expecting to see nice ligatures for fi and ff. But no luck. I tried using helvet package instead of avant. I also tried compiling using latex and xelatex. But no luck.

What do I need to do to get the proper ligatures?

Comment: I get ligatures. Is there really no difference to `f\/f`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are ligatures but they are not as clearly visual as for the serif font. In my MWE, I am showing the serif and sans serif version, both with and without ligature. You see that the effect is not that big in sans serif, but it exists:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avant}     
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}   

\begin{document}
    fi ff

    f\/i f\/f
    \sffamily 

    fi ff

    f\/i f\/f
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not like these 'ligatures' (actually just some tighter kerning), you will have to speak to the font maintainer or switch to another font.

Answer (score 5):

Fonts are not required to have ligatures; for instance, Hermann Zapf's Palatino has none *by design*.

The AvantGarde font clone distributed with TeX (actually URW GothicL, which is free) has ligatures in the canonical positions, but they don't appear different from setting `f` next to `f`, `i` or `l`. Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avant}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}                                                                                                
\begin{document}
\showoutput
fi ff
\end{document}
```

This is what's found in the `.log` file:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 539.94232fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 2.47511
...\hbox(7.52489+0.0)x345.0, glue set 316.68018fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/pag/m/n/10 ^^L (ligature fi)
....\glue 2.7699 plus 1.6599 minus 0.65991
....\OT1/pag/m/n/10 
                     (ligature ff)
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 22.62007
..\hbox(7.37993+0.0)x345.0, glue set 169.73004fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/pag/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

As you see, characters for the ligatures are chosen. On the other hand, the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avant}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}                                                                                                

\begin{document}
\sbox0{fi}\texttt{\the\wd0}

\sbox0{f{}i}\texttt{\the\wd0}
\end{document}
```

prints

[image]

so we see that the ligature `fi` consists in just moving the `i` a bit nearer to the `f` (by 0.27pt, slightly less than 0.1mm). Similarly for `ff` and `fl`.

There's no need to make a “real” ligature in this case, which is similar to the case of Palatino, because the curve of the `f` doesn't extend past the bounding box, like it happens in most serif fonts (and also sans serif ones).